# convert string to long long

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008

I'm using VS 2008 to create a C++ DLL (not managed) project and I need convert a char* to a long long type. Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It seems this question pops up every week or so :-|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `_atoi64.`  This takes `char*` and returns `__int64`.

Comment: Buyer beware: atoi is not type safe nor does it offer any bounds checking!

Comment: Yeah, _atoi64 is probably not a good choice. If you're using .NET framework, why not use ToInt64 on a String instead of a char*. If not, I think strtol or it's equiv is the current standard way to go and is safer than atoi.

Comment: in case you think this is a good solution (i.e., aren't worried about type safety/bound checking) and are using linux / osx, you can use atoll().

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way is to use the std::stringstream (it's also the most typesafe...)

```
std::stringstream sstr(mystr);
__int64 val;
sstr >> val;
```

You may need to target a 64-bit application for this to work.

[C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.2)

Comment: You should use `std::int64_t` instead of the MSVC `__int64` language extension.

Comment: I don't think std::int64_t is available on VC++ 2008

Answer (score 7):

If you're using boost, lexical_cast is the way to go, in my opinion.

```
long long ll = boost::lexical_cast<long long>(mystr)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using stoll() found within the string library. Takes a C++ string.

```
long long ll = std::stoll(mystr);
```

[Docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoll/)